# EditText above soft keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I know this question has a lot of different variations and different answers.

But, all the answers that I have seen are solved using plain editText (without a container or background). So, even I tried using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and all its variations and combinations according to the answers I searched for in all the other SO threads.

So, here I am again presenting my problem with an `EditText` inside a container, which is still half-covered by the soft keyboard after trying all the solutions I could find. My screen looks something like this:

[See `EditText` is not totally above the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHrHP.jpg)

My layout hierarchy is some what like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_direct_chat_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back_white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_direct_chat_name"
    style="@style/PrimaryBold16"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ib_direct_chat_close"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ib_direct_chat_close"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ib_direct_chat_close" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_direct_chat_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dimen8"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_direct_chat_sendMessage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ib_direct_chat_close" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_direct_chat_sendMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen15"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen15"
    android:background="@drawable/tablet_grey_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_direct_chat_message"
        style="@style/PrimaryRegular14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/add_comment"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dimen15"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_direct_chat_sendIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen15"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_chat_message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/et_chat_message"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_chat_message"
        app:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know this might be a noob question but this is really taking up my time, as you can see from the image the solution is stuck in an imperfect manner.

**EDIT:** I just added `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` in my manifest and it works perfectly now in my Android phone targeting API 30 but the issue persists in my phone targeting API 28

Comment: Please include the source code of the XML for checking what constraint you have done.

Comment: Please provide the code for your message container.

Comment: @SurajBahadur added the layout xml

Comment: @AnantaRaha added the whole layout code

Comment: Try `RelativeLayout` as Parent layout instead of `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score -2):

android:windowSoftInputMode=”stateVisible|adjustPan

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that this solution does not solve my problem. Also while using this, the topmost contents of my recyclerView are hidden along with the imageButton and TextView.